# Angular Different routes same component

Tags: angular, typescript

i made this in my app.routing.ts:

```
{ path: 'profile/questionnaire', canActivate: [ AuthGuard], component: UprofileComponent},
```

And  this in my html file :

```
<div id="testButton">  
    <button class="col-md-3" id="colorBBox" routerLink="profile/test" (click)="hide();">Test1</button>
</div>

<div id="showTest1 style="display:none;> ...</div>
```

by clicking the button "hide()" is called:

```
 hide(){
    document.getElementById('testButton').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('showTest1').style.display = 'block';
    this.showTest1();
 }
```

Problem:   should be routerLink="profile" and  should be routerLink="profile/test" ... both of them are routerLink="profile".. any ideas? Both divs share one html an on .ts file

Comment: Clarification: Do you want to change link but hide/show div, right?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: But I will suggest you, don't. Because when user will refresh the page, it will not display the right div, if you really want in that way then you have to make a check on router as well.

Comment: thank you for your help, maybe I can seperate it into two components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your desired result, you can change URL from component.
Import `Router` from `@angular/router`

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

then inject into constructor

```
constructor(private router:Router) {
}
```

then navigate from `hide()` function based on some condition

```
this.router.navigate(['profile/test']);
```